# minimum value of $x^{\ln(y)-\ln(z)}+y^{\ln(z)-\ln(x)}+z^{\ln(x)-\ln(y)}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> If $x,y,z>0.$ Then minimum value of
>
> $x^{\ln(y)-\ln(z)}+y^{\ln(z)-\ln(x)}+z^{\ln(x)-\ln(y)}$

what i try

Let $\ln(x)=a,\ln(y)=b.\ln(z)=c$

So $x=e^{a},y=e^{b},z=e^{c}$

How do i solve it help me

Comment: one idea is take the partial derivatives in $a,b,c$ then set this equal to zero.

Comment: *Hint:* $x^{\ln(y)-\ln(z)} \cdot y^{\ln(z)-\ln(x)} \cdot z^{\ln(x)-\ln(y)} = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Useful fact**
>
> $$\large x^{\log y}=y^{\log x}$$
>
> Also refer to another answer of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879477/logarithms-equality/1879607#1879607).

Let $u=x^{\ln y}$, $v=y^{\ln z}$ and $w=z^{\ln x}$, then $u,v,w\in \mathbb{R}^+$

\begin{align}
  f(x,y,z) &= x^{\ln y-\ln z}+y^{\ln z-\ln x}+z^{\ln x-\ln y} \\
  &= \frac{u}{w}+\frac{v}{u}+\frac{w}{v} \\
  & \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{u}{w} \times \frac{v}{u} \times \frac{w}{v}}
  \tag{by AM $\ge$ GM} \\
  &= 3
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

After your substitution you get what seems like a more manageable
$$
f(a,b,c) = e^{a(b-c)} + e^{b(c-a)} + e^{c(a-b)}
$$
and you can now minimize easily using the standard techniques.

Comment: No need for standard techniques I guess, AM-GM inequality works and gives the minimum as 3.